# Update Magento default product placeholder images within theme files

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.4.3.p1, placeholder-image

I'm trying to override the default Magento logo product placeholder images within my theme, however, the results are inconsistent.  I need to do this so it can be tracked in code versus manually by uploading via DB so they are in place automatically by using the theme when we deploy an instance.

I added 4 image files in the following location `app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/Magento_Catalog/web/images/product/placeholder/`

- image.jpg
- small_image.jpg
- swatch_image.jpg
- thumbnail.jpg

Then I ran the following just to be safe and nuke all the things...

```
$ rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/di/ var/generation/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
$ bin/magento c:f
$ bin/magento catalog:imag:res
```

This appeared to work for me the first time as I was able to see the new placeholder image on the frontend on the PLP and PDP.  Then I tested removing these files and I got the original Magento placeholder.  However, when I put the images back in place and ran the 3 commands to clear out the cache and such... I am still seeing the default Magento placeholder.  I confirmed that it is not being browser cached and I get the same results when opening an incognito window.

Is there a cache or setting that I am missing to make this work consistently?

I'm running Magento Enterprise (Adobe Commerce) v2.4.3-p1 with Warden on my Mac M1.